# Checkbox is not checking

Tags: ios, swift, checkbox, uibutton

I have a method that gets called when a button (checkbox) is clicked that should change the background image of the button. I have an NSLog that tells me that the method was called but the image never changes. I can't figure out why.

Thanks for the help!

```
let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checkedBox")
let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "uncheckedBox")

var isChecked:Bool = false

func checkboxClicked(sender: UIButton!) {
    if sender == self {
        if isChecked == true {
            NSLog("Change background image - checked")
            sender.setBackgroundImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
            isChecked == false
        } else {
            NSLog("Change background image - unchecked")
            sender.setBackgroundImage(uncheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
            isChecked == true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint at the beginning of the method to determine how far it gets? That'd be a good place to start. http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/01/14/using-breakpoints-in-xcode

Comment: Where is the func checkboxClicked(sender: UIButton!) code situated, is it in the controller code - if yes, then your problem is the line where you check if sender == self, because the self will be the controller and not the view...I need more context to really help you

Comment: @user3435374 My apologies, the checkboxClicked method is in a separate Checkbox class that the checkbox buttons are associated with. Like in the Identity Inspector I have chose the class Checkbox from the dropdown.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your question.  The only thing if the NSLog statements are printing that could be wrong is that the control state of the buttons could be something other than .Normal

Comment: @kpont Just did that and it seems like to begin with on the first click that `sender.setBackgroundImage(uncheckedImage, forState: .Normal)` is called and then isChecked is changed to true (it is initialized as false)

Comment: @user3435374 Hm, do you know how I could figure out what the control state is?

Comment: There is a readonly state property on the UIButton control https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/state

Comment: Oh, I just edited the NSLog to tell me which setBackgroundImage is being called and it turns out it just keeps setting it to unchecked which gives the appearance it's not working. I wonder what I did wrong hmm.

Comment: Oh wow I figured it out, when I change the state of isChecked I was using == instead of =, hahah, so the state was never changing

Answer (score 0):

You could always just set the different images for the different states.

```
let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checkedBox")
let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "uncheckedBox")

checkbox.setBackgroundImage(checkedImage, forState: .Selected);
checkbox.setBackgroundImage(uncheckedImage, forState: .Normal);

var isChecked:Bool = false

func checkboxClicked(sender: UIButton!) {
    if sender == self {
        sender.selected = isChecked;
        isChecked = !isChecked;
    }
}
```

This way, you can even set an image for when it is highlighted to add a bit of flare to clicking the checkbox.